# How do I rotate a camera around the Y axis of the object it's looking at?

Tags: mathematics, camera, vector

I'm making a camera that can currently rotate freely from the back to the front of a target object by giving it an angle and a distance.

[image]

I do the above with the following code

```
directionVector = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin (angle*Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle));
normalizedDirectionVector = (directionVector).normalized;

transform.position = (normalizedDirectionVector*cameraDistance) + target.transform.position;
```

In the above I take the direction from the angle, normalize it and then add it to the target position. And the camera sets nicely to the wanted angle. But how can I add the sideways movement(x-component) so that I could move the camera freely around the target?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the original angle vector and then using the equation that @nykwil provided, but only using the pitch component. Then I combined the y-component of the angle vector to the pitch and I got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Google Euler angle conversion for more info.  To get a direction vector from a pitch and a yaw (pitch is what you have now and yaw is around the vertical axis) you want this:

```
x = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch)
y = sin(yaw)*cos(pitch)
z = sin(pitch)
```

Comment: I tried this approach it worked fantastically when e.g editing yaw with pitch as zero. But when both had values the rotation became limited.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage for [gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) might be of use. That is deprecated now days in OpenGL itself, but glm has an implementation. Then you just use that plus basic trigonometry for working out the X/Y coordinates of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

You could use engine features to avoid trigonometry entirely. Another way to achieve this is to do the following steps:

1. Set the camera's position equal to the target position.
2. Rotate the camera such that it points in the direction you want.
3. Add the desired displacement to the **local translation** of the camera. This will automatically move the camera away from the target. (Note: depending on the axes you are using, this might mean adding `<0, 0, orbitRadius>` or `<0, 0, -orbitRadius>`.)

It looks like you're using Unity, which has the tools to make this extremely simple.